# Setting the default java compiler

Tags: java, compilation, default

I have openjdk 1.8 installed via yum in '/usr/bin/java' and I have also downloaded the Oracle Java Hotspot 1.7 compiler in `/opt/devel/jdk_1.7'
I updated my PATH in my ~/.bashrc file to include`/opt/dvel/jdk_1.7/bin'

When I run `which java` the terminal only responds with '/usr/bin/java'

1. Why is the other java compiler in '/opt/devel/jdk_1.7/bin' not being found?
2. How can I make this other compiler be the default compiler when executing java?

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` return? The very first path containing java dictates which version is executed. Note that the requirement to set JAVA_HOME in order to execute java is a fallacy.

Answer (score 1):

I would set JAVA_HOME too in ~/.bashrc

Setting JAVA_HOME

```
jdk7oracle=/opt/devel/jdk_1.7 
export JAVA_HOME=$jdk7oracle export
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

and then test using

```
java -version
```

Also make sure you start a new terminal session so that bashrc is reloaded after your edits. OR you can source the bashrc file if you don't want to restart terminal.

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: still not doing anything - meaning what? What is the output of "java -version" command?